# how to create a navigation bar like pulse android app

Tags: android-layout, android

I was trying to figure out how to create navigation bar like pulse android app see the screen shot

[image]

is it a navigation bar or a tabbed bar or something else?. How can i create something like this? Also when i clicks on any of the option does it goes to a new activity??

Thanks Pranay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in the image it's looks like this to me: [viewFlow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow).Hope it's help!

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like ViewPager as used in Google+ app.
It should be available in Honeycomb and also in the [Compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).